# CSV End of line

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter, end-of-line

Hi i am trying to put end of line code in CSV format to import it to excel I tried putting
\n, "\n", \r, "\r", \r\n, "\r\n" but nothing worked for me I am trying to import it in excel 2013 my csv format is like below

```
Medicine;1213;22;19\nMedicine (miscellaneous);1013;32;55\nEngineering;708;14;21
```

please help. Field delimiter working fine but how to manage line break I want out put like this

```
Medicine                   | 1213 | 22 | 19   
Medicine (miscellaneous)   | 1013 | 32 | 55   
Engineering                | 708  | 14 |21
```

Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Comment: Does your original input file actually have any kind of line separator?  Or, is it just all on a single line?  Also, which text editor are you using to modify your CSV file?

Comment: yes it just all on a single line that why it is not working any idea on it ?

Comment: Are you certain there are no line separators there?  Just because it renders on a single line does not mean there are no separators.  If nothing really is there, then you might have to add them to get the Excel import to work.

Comment: yes there is \n for line separators but that is not working

Comment: Do you have access to Notepad++?

Comment: yes I have Notepad++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can just do the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
\\n
```

**Replace:**

```
\n
```

Be certain to do this in regex mode, not regular mode.

Answer (score 1):

CSV uses [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). So the comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/42666642/9179591 is incorrect. Most use cases are going that the EOL of csv is CR/LF.

In Unix(Ubuntu in my case), you can look it, when you open your file in `cat -A /<someYourFilePath>`

Answer (score 0):

if the above is your text file. I have found that just pressing enter works in the text file.

example:

```
Medicine;1213;22;19
Medicine (miscellaneous);1013;32;55
Engineering;708;14;21
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The \n is just text to Excel. I used Word to Replace \n with Special Character Paragraph Code then saved as a txt file and that imported into Excel.